# What does the notation " BasicFileAttributes.class " mean in java7?

Tags: java, java-7, nio

Here's the code

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

At the link
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html ,they say BasicFileAttributes is a class. But the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html calls it an interface.(Please clear this confusion if you know, although this isn't the main problem)


**Main Problem:** 
I can't understand **BasicFileAttributes.class** parameter. Are they trying to pass a class as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BasicFileAttributes is an interface, but it is common in colloquial expression to use the phrase such as "BasicFileAttributes class" to mean "a class that implements BasicFileAttributes".

As for your main question, you are passing an instance of the special Java class `java.lang.Class`. So no, you are not "passing a class in" (that concept is in fact meaningless in Java). You are passing such an instance of `java.lang.Class` that **describes the interface** `BasicFileAttributes`.

This is similar to when you pass an instance of `File` to a method: you are not passing the actual file in, but an object through which that file can be managed.

Comment: Ok, i searched and found that **instance** and **object** are the same.    So your words **You are passing such an instance of java.lang.Class that describes the interface BasicFileAttributes** mean that **BasicFileAttributes.class** parameter is passing an object. I hope i am right to say that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. An object is an instance of its class.

Answer (score 3):

[`BasicFileAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) is defined as an interface because it specifies behavior (in this case, accessor methods for file attribute information) and there are subclasses which provide this in an implementation-defined manner. The documentation page lists `DosFileAttributes` and `PosixFileAttributes` as known subclasses.

An interface can be used as a declared type to keep the basic behavior contract the same. In other words, when I have a `BasicFileAttributes` object, I don't know if it's really a `DosFileAttributes` or a `PosixFileAttributes` under the hood, and I don't care. All I care about is that I can call any of the `BasicFileAttributes` methods on it and get the results I'm expecting.

As for the [`Files.readAttributes`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) method, yes, you are passing a class in. In this case, you can either get the basic file attributes using `BasicFileAttributes.class`, or you can pass in one of its subclasses and get the platform-specific information (at the risk of having to deal with an `UnsupportedOperationException` if you're asking for attributes that don't exist on your platform).

Comment: You cannot "pass a class in". I don't think it is OK to confuse a newbie with statements like that.

Comment: Yes... you can. More precisely, you pass in a `Class` object that refers to the class, interface, or enum definition itself and on which you can query its metadata using reflection. In Java 1.5+, the `Class` objects use generics to indicate the exact type of the class object, for example `Class<BasicFileAttributes>`.

Comment: There, you said it yourself: you pass in an **object**, not a **class**.

Comment: It's an object representing a class. Are you now going to tell me I'm not allowed to say that I want to use a string, or a File, or an int? Do I have to say "an object representing a string", "an object of the File class", or "a piece of primitive data that is of type int"? Don't be such a prescriptivist. I'm using the same grammar that pretty much everyone else does. I used more precise language to disambiguate things at your implied request; now you're just being a pedantic prick. Just shut up, idiot.

Comment: As I said quite clearly: don't confuse beginners with such colloquialisms. OP has posed this question precisely because he is confused about this distinction. Maybe you just lack the mental wherewithal to notice these subtle (to you) clues in the text of the question. If that is so, well I suppose you can be excused, but my advice was for OP's benefit, not for yours. As a side note, the distinction between "class" and "object representing a class" is not at all about grammar. In both cases you are using the exact same grammar: that of the English language.

Comment: Another point: `BasicFileAttributes.class` **is not an object representing a class**. Here everyone can see exactly into what slippery terrain your colloquialism brings you. This is no way to explain these concepts to a newbie.

Comment: Actually, the grammar is different: the grammar I and many others use, compared to the grammar that you want me to use. If you prefer, you could assume I am referring to a grammar subset preference. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription#Prescription_and_description for more.

Comment: Ufff... the full vastness of your miscomprehension is only starting to dawn on me. Let me put it in simpler terms, then. "Class" is a noun; "object representing a class" is a noun phrase using a participial adjective post-modified by its object. Both of them conform to the standard English grammar. Whether this grammar is descriptive or prescriptive, I leave to you to ponder.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik & PlatinumAzure: This discussion leads me to the conclusion that **BasicFileAttributes.class** is passing an object (in layman's  language). Am I right?

Comment: @ManeetSingh I did my best to explain it in my answer. Perhaps read it and leave a comment there in case of any further clarifications needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Are they trying to pass a class as parameter?

Yes.

Interfaces have associated `.class` files that describe their metadata also. The suffix here, or the use of a class file, does not necessarily mean that the type being referred to is a "class" as in it is not an interface or an enum.